# Implementing a string based calendar in C#

Tags: c#

I *want* to create a C# program that displays a calendar and uses a string that contains the names of the days:

```
string Names = "Sun,Mon,Tues,Wed,Thurs,Fri,Sat,";
```

So far I have....

```
int weeks = 1;
int days = 1;
string Names = "Sun,Mon,Tues,Wed,Thurs,Fri,Sat,";
string dayName;
int commaIndex = 0;
int date = 1;
while (weeks < 5) 
{ 
    while (days < 8) 
    { 
        commaIndex = Names.IndexOf(","); // find the period 
        dayName = Names.Remove(commaIndex); 
        lblCalendar.Text += dayName + "." + " " + date + " "; 
        Names = Names.Remove(0, commaIndex + 1);

        days++; 
        date++; 
    } 
    weeks++;
}
```

But that only writes the first week.. can anybody help me figure out where there is an error?

Comment: You have to set days = 1 after the first while, otherwise you won't be able to enter the inner while-loop the next week.

Comment: just use `for` loops instead.  You are instantiating variables only to use them as indexes.  That's a `for` loop

Comment: There's a few problems: 1. You're mutating the `Names` string, and so after the first week, `Names` will be empty. 2. You're not resetting `days` after the loop. 3. Your date always starts on the `1st` and for a `Sunday`. Why not just use the built-in `DateTime.DayOfWeek` ?

Comment: Are you doing it that way because it's needed, or because you don't know about arrays?

Comment: no arrays werent allowed

Answer (score 3):

First, you forgot to restart days variable after every iteration. 
Also, after first iteration your `Names` string is empty. 
I suggest to create array of day names and use it instead of one string.

```
        int weeks = 1;
        int days = 1;

        var Names = new[] {"Sun", "Mon", "Tues", "Wed", "Thurs", "Fri", "Sat" };

        string dayName;
        int commaIndex = 0;
        int date = 1;
        while (weeks < 5)
        {
            while (days < 8)
            {

                dayName = Names[days-1];
                lblCalendar.Text += dayName + "." + " " + date + " ";

                days++;
                date++;
            }
            days = 1;
            weeks++;
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to reset days.

```
while (weeks < 5) 
{ 
    days = 1
    string Names = "Sun,Mon,Tues,Wed,Thurs,Fri,Sat,";

    while (days < 8) 
    {
```

Comment: No, you're not. Common mistake :)

Comment: This will still break, `Names` will be `""` after the first loop

Comment: @Frode also, wouldnt the Names = Names.Remove() part be an issue as well? I'm not too familiar with c#, but it appears to me that that would remove the names from the string after one iteration of the outer loop.

Comment: Yes, Names must be initialized just above or below days = 1